# Expand/Minimize UITableView Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my App, I have `UITableView` with custom XIB cell, when the user click on any cell the cell should expand and show content, if he click on it again the cell should Minimize.
My Problem is, If there is any cell expanded before, and the user click on another cell the first cell should be minimized first, then this cell will get expanded.

I am using : `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)`

but it doesn't work. 
any one faced problem like this before?

I will be so thankful for any help.

Comment: Try this:- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/

Answer (score 2):

You can try these following steps:

- define

  ```
  var expandHeight: CGFloat = 100
  var normalHeight: CGFloat  = 50.0
  var currentSelected = 0
  ```
- use them in

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

          if indexPath.row == currentSelected {

              return expandHeight
          }
          else {

              return normalHeight
          }
      }
  ```
- call it in

  ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       tableView.beginUpdates()

       currentSelected = indexPath.row

       tableView.endUpdates()
   }
  ```

Comment: Nice solution but will not animate the cell to make it big and small.

Comment: @Vakas: it animates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Write following algorithm in didSelectRowAtIndexpath: delegate method on UITableView.

1) Check whether any cell is already expanded or not?(Can check by maintaining indexPath property variable, which helps to get that cell again to perform any operation with cellForRowAtIndexpath:).

2) If YES, set that tableview's cell's height to default, say 44.0, else do nothing.

3) Then apply the expanded cell function(Method to expand cell) on selected cell and also update indexPath property with new selected cell's indexPath.